# Facebook API: Post to wall with multiline message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbjs

I'm posting to a User's wall using the [Post API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/). I want the message which gets posted to have line breaks and links. Eg -

[screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5154158/shot.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5154158/shot.png)

Line 1 (Sid is ...) is Post#title.

Line 2 (Venmo is.. ) is Post#description

Line 3 and 4 (See more and If you) look to be Post#message. Its a link and there is a line break.

I want to achieve line 3. The documentation says Post#message is a JSON string, so far I've tried giving it HTML (tags get stripped), encoded tags( tags get printed instead of actually applied) - nothing seems to be working.

Not sure how to go about this ? Ideas anyone ?

Comment: Line 3 => caption, Line 4=> message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can at least do something "similar" this ways:

1) Pass your link target as "link" parameter and "see more" as caption.

2) pass an actions parameter like this:

`{"name": "see more", "link": "http://mylinktarget.foo"}`

Comment: I'm looking for a line breaks solution as well.  This is definitely not it.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks do not work but using  tags does.

```
{"description":"<center>line 1</center><center>line 2</center>"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook API appears to honor ASCII Code 10 for newlines.

Comment: you have an example of how to put it?

Answer (score 0):

%0A works for line break. I have tested with postman.